# Comparing mysql tables and update a value

Tags: mysql, function, compare

I want to compare real results and predictions from 2 similar tables on mysql.

real

```
 id | data1| data2 |
```

user

```
 id | data1| data2 | points
```

ranking

```
 id | user| total points
```

I want to do the following:

```
 if (real.data1 = user.data1) AND (real.data2 = user.data2)
 update user set points=8 where id=1
 else if(real.data1 > user.data1) AND (real.data2 > user.data2)
 update user set points=4 where id=1
 else if (real.data1 = real.data2) AND (user.data1 = user.data2)
 update user set points=4 where id=1
  else if (real.data1 < user.data1) AND (real.data2 < user.data2)
  update user set points=4 where id=1
        else
            update user set points=0 where id=1      
   sum all values from points and update ranking table
```

Is it possible?

Comment: This is confusing. Probably will help if you provide a modicum of sample data and desired output.

Comment: For example, the real result of a match is home_team 2 (data1) - 0 (data2) away team
and my prediction( user table) was 2 - 0 i won 8 points, if my prediction was 3 -0 i won 4 points, and if my prediction was 0 - 1 or 2-2, 0 points,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the below will work for the first half of your question, but I have not tested it:

```
UPDATE `user` u
 INNER JOIN `real` r ON (u.id = r.id)
SET    u.points = IF(r.data1 = u.data1 and r.data2 = u.data2,
                     8,
                     IF(r.data1 > u.data1 and r.data2 > u.data2,
                        4,
                        IF(r.data1 = r.data2 and u.data1 = u.data2,
                           4,
                           IF(r.data1 < u.data1 and r.data2 < u.data2,
                              4,
                              0)
                          )
                       )
                    )
```

See the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) concerning the IF statement if this doesn't make sense.